# When click button change text in code tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a code box you can see in image . My question is how can ı change code in code tag  when click another language button ?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center py-1">
    <div class="embedcontainer">
      <button class="language">JavaScript</button>
      <button class="language">PHP</button>
      <div class="code-wrapper">
        <pre>
                  <code id="code">
&nbsp;function&nbsp;fibonacci(num)<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;{<br/>   var&nbsp;num1=0;<br/>   var&nbsp;num2=1;<br/>   var&nbsp;sum;<br/>  var&nbsp;i=0;<br/>  for&nbsp;(i&nbsp;=&nbsp;0;&nbsp;i&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;num;&nbsp;i++)<br/>    &nbsp;&nbsp;{<br/>      sum=num1+num2;<br/>     num1=num2;<br/>     num2=sum;<br/>  &nbsp;&nbsp;}<br/>  &nbsp;&nbsp;return&nbsp;num2;<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;}<br/>        &nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log(fibonacci(155));

              </pre>
        <button id="copy-button">Copy</button>
      </div>
      <span id="copy-success">Code copied!</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: this is not an image of the code @0stone0

Comment: You have to write a code for other language.

Comment: ı know ofcourse but how can ı change on template @FaeemazazBhanej

Comment: If this is some sort of tutorial, it'll probably be easier to have two separate boxes, one for each language, and show/hide the boxes instead.

Comment: It will be better if you store the codes in some kind of variables and then according to the button click change the innerHTML of the element containing the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put some Javascript code. If click on **JavaScript** tab, display `none` **PHP** tab data and if click on **PHP** tab, display `none` the **Javascript** tab data.

Here down is code:

```js
function openTab(evt, languageName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(languageName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center py-1">
    <div class="embedcontainer">
      
      <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'JavaScript')">JavaScript</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'PHP')">PHP</button>
      </div>
      
      <div id="JavaScript" class="tabcontent">
        <pre>
            <code id="code">
                JavaScript code
            </code>
        </pre>
        <button id="copy-button">Copy</button>
      </div>

      <div id="PHP" class="tabcontent">
        <pre>
            <code id="code">
                PHP code
            </code>
        </pre>
        <button id="copy-button">Copy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```